# Ubuntu: service --status-all can't be with | more or | grep git

Tags: linux, ubuntu, service, grep

Ubuntu: `service --status-all` can't be with `| more` or `| grep git`

I see long list of running services, I just can't see it by page or filter it. The above additons don't affect output.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and should be on askubuntu.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `service --status-all` uses `stderr` and `stdout`. `grep` or `more` does not affect on `stderr`. We need to use redirection.

```
service --status-all 2>&1 | grep git
service --status-all 2>&1 | more
```